# Trigger Repeater Drop down event JQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I wanted to add value quantity and piece type every time the user has selected a drop down value.Currently I can only achieve this using the "add" button which codes is I have posted below posted below not by drop down.

[image]

Here is my code for the jquery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var count           =       0;
        var count_piece     =       0;
        var price           =       0;
        var total           =       0;
        var documents       =       "Documents (Up to 1kg)";
        var small           =       "Small (1-5kg 85cm)";
        var medium          =       "Medium (5-10kg 110cm)";
        var large           =       "Large (10-20kg 150cm)";
        var extra           =       "Extra Large (20-30kg 160cm)";

        $("input[value='Add']").click(function (){

            var qty           =    $('input[name*="['+count+++'][qty]"]').val();
            var piece_type    =    $('select[name*="['+count_piece+++'][piece_type]"]').find(":selected").text();

            if(piece_type == documents)
            {
                price = 10;
                var sum = parseFloat(qty) * parseFloat(price);

                total += sum;
            }

            if(piece_type == small)
            {
                price = 20;
                var sum = parseFloat(qty) * parseFloat(price);

                total += sum;
            }

            if(piece_type == medium)
            {
                price = 30;
                var sum = parseFloat(qty) * parseFloat(price);

                total += sum;
            }

            if(piece_type == large)
            {
                price = 40;
                var sum = parseFloat(qty) * parseFloat(price);

                total += sum;
            }

            if(piece_type == extra)
            {
                price = 50;
                var sum = parseFloat(qty) * parseFloat(price);

                total += sum;
            }

            $("#wpc_total").text("Total : $"+total);
        });


    });
```

and my html markup

```
     <tbody data-repeater-list="pq_package_items">
   <tr data-repeater-item>
    <td><input class="number" type='text' name="qty" required="required"/></td>
    <td>
       <select name="piece_type" required="required">
           <option value="">Select Type</option>
           <option value="Documents (Up to 1kg)">Documents (Up to 1kg)</option>
           <option value="Small (1-5kg 85cm)">Small (1-5kg 85cm)</option>
           <option value="Medium (5-10kg 110cm)">Medium (5-10kg 110cm)</option>
       </select>
   </td>
   <td><input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete"/></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I'm using this [Jquery Repeater](https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater) from github. I tried this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/55sstjtn/6/) of mine as a test but its not working on wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, on dropdownselection, you want to execute the same function as on Add click...

I make that function a named function... And call it on `input` click **and** on `select` change.

**EDIT**, since the [Repeater pluging](https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater) clones your table rows, use [delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) too.

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var count           =       0;
  var count_piece     =       0;
  var price           =       0;
  var total           =       0;
  var documents       =       "Documents (Up to 1kg)";
  var small           =       "Small (1-5kg 85cm)";
  var medium          =       "Medium (5-10kg 110cm)";
  var large           =       "Large (10-20kg 150cm)";
  var extra           =       "Extra Large (20-30kg 160cm)";

  function checkTotal(){

    var qty           =    $("input[name*='qty']");  //.val();
    var piece_type    =    $("select[name*='piece_type']");  //.find(":selected").text();

    qty.each(function(index){

      var quantity = qty.eq(index).val();

      if(piece_type.eq(index).find(":selected").text() == documents)
      {
        price = 10;
        var sum = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);

        total += sum;
      }

      if(piece_type.eq(index).find(":selected").text() == small)
      {
        price = 20;
        var sum = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);

        total += sum;
      }

      if(piece_type.eq(index).find(":selected").text() == medium)
      {
        price = 30;
        var sum = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);

        total += sum;
      }

      if(piece_type.eq(index).find(":selected").text() == large)
      {
        price = 40;
        var sum = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);

        total += sum;
      }

      if(piece_type.eq(index).find(":selected").text() == extra)
      {
        price = 50;
        var sum = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);

        total += sum;
      }

      $("#wpc_total").text("Total : $"+total);
    });
  }

  $(document).on("click", "input[value='Add']", checkTotal);
  $(document).on("change", "select[name*='piece_type']", checkTotal);
});
```

Comment: Oh its working.And more neat that mine.But `$("select[name*='piece_type']").change(checkTotal);` is only working on the first row of the repeater. I tried this before can't figure out why.

Comment: I just re-edited... Sorry... lol It should work with this last one.

Comment: is `checktotal` missing a closing bracket?

Comment: I fixed it.but its still not working.Did I miss something?

Comment: It's working on the add.The dropdown is still only working on the first row.

Comment: Sorry... This was the `.each` that had a missing close bracket

Comment: It seems to work in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/EvJxao?editors=1011). Is it working on your side?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153823/discussion-between-rai-nalasa-and-louys-patrice-bessette).